# Running azure webjob with GDI requirements

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Does anyone know what the status is of running an Azure webjob that has GDI requirement? I known there has been an issue, but can't find any status on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rasmus,
Fix was supposed to be deployed - try it out and post info on any issues here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ed5c738-390a-4ca7-81d0-370124a4fc88/windows-azure-web-sites-faq?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Known Issues
1. Components rely on GDI API may not work on Azure Web Sites. The workaround is moving to Azure Web Role. [Jun 12/A fix has been deployed to SN data center. Please try and let us know if you have any problem.]

-Simon.

Comment: My own worksround is just to spin up an azure vm and run the job as a console app. Both this and the web role is not as frictionless as could be. I'll look at the thread.

Comment: What is SN datacenter??

Comment: Apparently only for Basic and Standard sites too, not free or shared. Just verifying this myself...

Comment: Does anyone have any tutorials on how to move something to a web role?